# adding arithmetic values to dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary, as shown below.

```
band1= {'channel1': 10564, 'channel2': 10589, 'channel3': 10612, 'channel4': 10637,'channel5': 10662, 'channel6': 10687,
'channel7': 10712, 'channel8': 10737, 'channel9': 10762, 'channel10': 10787,'channel11': 10812, 'channel12': 10837, }
```

I'd like a nice way of editing this dictionary. To each entry I want another value added with is the value/5 and a third value entered with is value/5-190

The dictionary would then look like(with the expressions actually converted to their final values):

```
band1= {'channel1': [10564, 10564/5, 10564/5-190], 'channel2': [10589,10589/5,10589/5-190], 'channel3': [10612,10612/5,10612/5-190], 'channel4': [10637,10637/5,10637/5-190],
'channel5': [10662,10662/5,10662/5-190], 'channel6': [10687,10687/5,10687/5-190],
'channel7': [10712, 10712/5, 10712/5-190], 'channel8': [10737,10737/5,10737/5-190], 'channel9': [10762,10762/5,10762/5-190], 'channel10': [10787,10787/5,10787/5-190],'channel11': [10812,10812/5,10812/5-190], 'channel12': [10837,10837/5,10837/5-190]}
```

I have to do this with a lot of entries so it would be better than just typing them all up if I could add them in a pythonic way. Also 5 or 190 is variable for other dictionaries so it would be nice to be able to vary this easily, another reason not to hard code. For instance another dictionary might have the rule that I need to divide by 4 and add 200 for second element, then for the third element I might have to add another variable number.

```
band2= {'channel1': [10564, 10564/4+200, 10564/4+200+100]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A dict comprehension will do the trick:

```
var1 = 5
var2 = -190
{k: [v, v/var1, v/var1+var2] for k, v in band1.iteritems()}
```

For Python 3, replace `.iteritems()` with just `.items()`, for Python 2.6 and before, use a generator expression to generate (key, value) tuples:

```
dict((k, [v, v/var1, v/var1+var2]) for k, v in band1.iteritems())
```

For your second dictionary `var1` and `var2` are then set to `4` and `200` respectively.

Demo:

```
>>> {k: [v, v/var1, v/var1+var2] for k, v in band1.iteritems()}
{'channel11': [10812, 2162, 1972], 'channel10': [10787, 2157, 1967], 'channel3': [10612, 2122, 1932], 'channel2': [10589, 2117, 1927], 'channel1': [10564, 2112, 1922], 'channel7': [10712, 2142, 1952], 'channel6': [10687, 2137, 1947], 'channel5': [10662, 2132, 1942], 'channel4': [10637, 2127, 1937], 'channel9': [10762, 2152, 1962], 'channel8': [10737, 2147, 1957], 'channel12': [10837, 2167, 1977]}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build the dictionary from scratch with values like these, which can take differnt form, I would go for small helper functions:

```
def manip1(k, a, b):
    return [k, k/a, k/a - b]

def manip2(k, a, b, c):
    return you_name_it(k, a, b, c)

# and then
band1['channel2'] = manip1(10564, 5, 190)
band1['channel3'] = manip2(10600, 5, 190, 200)
```

Comment: Thanks, that will be pretty helpful for using other formulae if I need to.

Answer (score 0):

Other option I think is a nice to mention is using strings:

```
band2= {'channel1': ['10564', '10564/4+200', '10564/4+200+100']
```

and then extract the value with `eval`:

```
>>> eval("10564/4+200")
2841
```